# При конвертации BMP в массив, массив в два раза больше нужного

Tags: c++-cli

```
public: array<Byte>^ imageToByteArray(System::Drawing::Image^ imageIn)
 {

             MemoryStream^ ms = gcnew MemoryStream();

             imageIn->Save(ms, System::Drawing::Imaging::ImageFormat::Bmp);
             ArrayTemp = ms->ToArray();

             ArrayToRet = gcnew array<Byte>((ArrayTemp->Length - HeaderForBMP.bfOffBits)/4);
             int t = 0;

             for (int i = HeaderForBMP.bfOffBits; i < ArrayTemp->Length; i+=4)
             {
                 ArrayToRet[t] = ArrayTemp[i];
                 t++;
             }

             return ArrayToRet;
}
```

Если конвертировать таким способом то маленькая картинка конвертируется отлично но стоить взять побольше как конвертируется массив двойной длины, то есть массив должен быть 100 байт а он 200, всегда ровно в два раза больше чем нужно